# Changes in xib not shown at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have seen simialr posts on this issue, but none of the answers have worked for me.

When I make changes to xibs in Interface Builder, they do not show at runtime. So far I have tried the following:

- Clean
- Clean Build Folder
- Reset Content on Simulator
- Restarted XCode
- Restarted the simulator

I've tried all of these steps in about every conceivable order, but still no changes in IB can be seen when I run the app. Earlier today, my changes were showing, so I do know that the xibs are definitely loading. I believe something has gotten hosed in XCode, perhaps? Any suggestions?

Comment: try saving the particular xib file when making changes in the view, more precisely click on the view in xib and hit save and then run.

Comment: Thanks, but no success there

Comment: try to change ur xib's name and see what happen, if it's working, try to change back to the previous name. you can give a shot

Comment: you can also delete the whole contents of the derived data folder, something like ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data. Another thing I did today was I was making changes in a copy of my project's directory while running the project from the original. use git.